# Paginate nested query of child posts

Tags: wp-query, pagination, child-pages, paginate-links

I need help with paginating the child posts created by Toolset on the page of the parent post. Basically, I need to recreate the functionality of this page http://dailytrendsetter.com/sports/top-10-premiere-league-goals-2016

I understand that at this website it's probably achieved via  tag, but my client is using child posts to show such top list.

I managed to pull all child posts in a loop, but I can't create similar pagination.

Please help! I've been pulling my hear over this question for so long! I think I tried everything, but I still can't make it work.

Current code in single.php

```
$postIDs = array();
$post_link = get_permalink();

$postFields = types_child_posts('sub-title-posts', array('ID' => $post->ID));

if ( $postFields ) {
  foreach ( $postFields as $postField ) {
    $postIDs[] = $postField->ID;
  }
}

$pages = count ($postFields);

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'sub-title-posts',
    'paged' => $paged,
    'post__in' => $postIDs,
    'posts_per_page' => 1
);

if( get_query_var('page') ) {
    $page = get_query_var( 'page' );
    } else {
    $page = 1;
}

$args['page'] = get_query_var( 'page' ) ? get_query_var( 'page' ) : 1;

$top = new WP_Query($args);

$temp_query = $wp_query;

$wp_query = NULL;

$wp_query = $top;

if ($top->have_posts()) {

    while ($top->have_posts()) { 
        $top->the_post();

        global $post;

        $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID);

        var_dump($meta);

    }//endwhile
    echo paginate_links( array(
        'base' => $post_link . '%#%' . '/',
        'format' => '?page=%#%',
        'current' => $page,
        'total' => $pages
    ));

 }//endif

wp_reset_postdata();

$wp_query = NULL;
$wp_query = $temp_query;
```

The result of the code: first post from the custom query in the var_dump and links under the post that lead to post_link/1, post_link/2, post_link/3... but at every link, there is the same first post from child posts query.

Comment: What is not working exactly? Note that on singular posts, the pagination query var is page, not paged. Also note that calling paginate_links with no arguments will produce no output, you must pass all of the necessary arguments.

Comment: @Milo Thank you for the reply! I updated code and added a description of the result. Could you please review?